# Getting Error on SubQuery in SQL

Tags: sql-server

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 277
>       Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
select 
    Book_Num, 
    Book_Title, 
    Book_SUBJECT, 
    AvgCost, 
    (Book_Cost - AvgCost) as 'Difference'
FROM 
    (
        Select 
            Book_Subject, 
            Avg(book_Cost) as AvgCost 
        from 
            BOOK 
        Group BY 
            BOOK_Subject
    )
;
```

Line 277 is the Group Line.  Not sure why I am getting this error, new to subqueries.

Comment: Give a name to your subquery: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) SubQResult`. Also: you're currently selecting fields which aren't available in your subquery. You might want to add those too if you want to see them in the end, unless you're not posting the full query here.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i posted my answer first itself  is there any wrong in that .@orgra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you need to name the subquery:

```
select 
    Book_Num, 
    Book_Title, 
    Book_SUBJECT, 
    AvgCost, 
    (Book_Cost - AvgCost) as 'Difference'
FROM 
    (
        Select 
            Book_Subject, 
            Avg(book_Cost) as AvgCost 
        from 
            BOOK 
        Group BY 
            BOOK_Subject
    ) AS Table1  -- <<< Add a name
;
```

But after correcting that error you will run in to the problem that you are selecting fields (`Book_Num` and `Book_Title`) in your main query that are not in your subquery.

You will need to join to another table to get those fields:

```
SELECT 
    Book_Num, 
    Book_Title, 
    Table1.Book_SUBJECT, -- <<< You'll need to qualify this field
    AvgCost, 
    (Book_Cost - AvgCost) as 'Difference'
FROM BOOK LEFT JOIN
    (
        Select 
            Book_Subject, 
            Avg(book_Cost) as AvgCost 
        from 
            BOOK 
        Group BY 
            BOOK_Subject
    ) AS Table1
ON BOOK.Book_SUBJECT = Table1.Book_Subject
;
```

Comment: Minor point, because neither the outer nor inner query filter the book table I'm sure what the outer join is bringing to the party?  That said; your answer is better than mine.  Instead of rewriting the query you've fixed the OPs original statement, which is what I should have done.  @Orgra I'd recommend [accepting this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The sub query is needed to provide an average price for a book subject, without it you would not be able to select individual book numbers/titles. Your answer replaces the sub query with a CTE, which is essentially a different type of sub query. Thanks for recommending my answer is accepted, but the OP may find your solution is better if they learn something new from it. :)

Comment: I was just thinking, as neither query filters the book table every subject must be both. Perhaps inner rather than a left join? Very minor point, feel bad for even mentioning it.

Comment: Don't feel bad, comments are the best way to ask for clarification of a question or answer. The reason I used a `LEFT JOIN` is we do not know if the `Book_Subject` field allows `NULL`. If it does, the `LEFT JOIN` will ensure _all_ books are returned. An `INNER JOIN` would exclude those books. Have a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca709/1

Comment: I'm British. The law requires me to feel bad and apologise hundreds of time a day! NULLS. Oh very clever. Of course, makes complete sense.

Comment: is there any mistake in my answer can u check it  @destination-data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.book_num, 
       a.book_title, 
       a.book_subject, 
       avgcost, 
       ( book_cost - avgcost ) AS 'Difference' 
FROM   (SELECT book_subject, 
               Avg(book_cost) AS AvgCost, 
               book_num, 
               book_title 
        FROM   book 
        GROUP  BY book_subject, 
                  book_num, 
                  book_title) A;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Book_Num, 
    Book_Title, 
    Book_SUBJECT, 
    AvgCost, 
    (Book_Cost - Avg(Book_Cost) over (partition by BOOK_Subject)) as 'Difference'
FROM 
Book
```

Try this query. It is much simpler. Doesn't use any sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
WITH cost 
AS
(
Select 
    Book_Subject, 
    Avg(book_Cost) as AvgCost 
from 
    BOOK 
Group BY 
    BOOK_Subject
)
SELECT bk.book_num
,      bk.book_title
,      bk.book_subject
,      cost.AvgCost
,      (bk.book_cost - cost.AvgCost) as 'Difference'
FROM   BOOK bk
JOIN   cost  ON bk.book_subject = cost.book_subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Without [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to be sure, but I think you are trying to return a list of books complete with the average cost for other books on the same subject.

My example uses a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) rather than a subquery, but the principle is the same.

```
/* Returns details on each book,
 * including the average price for the subject.
 */
WITH AvgCost AS
    (   
        -- Returns the average cost for each subject.
        Select 
            Book_Subject, 
            Avg(book_Cost) as AvgCost 
        from 
            BOOK 
        Group BY 
            BOOK_Subject
    )
-- Joins the average to the detail.
SELECT 
    bs.Book_Num, 
    bs.Book_Title, 
    bs.Book_SUBJECT, 
    ac.AvgCost, 
    (bs.Book_Cost - ac.AvgCost) as 'Difference'
FROM
    BOOK_Subject AS bs
        INNER JOIN AvgCost AS ac            ON ac.Book_Subject = bs.Book_Subject

;
```

An alternative approach is to use the [over clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).  This allows you to return inline aggregated totals.

```
-- Using the over clause.
SELECT 
    bs.Book_Num, 
    bs.Book_Title, 
    bs.Book_SUBJECT, 
    bs.book_Cost,
    Avg(bs.book_Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY  Book_Subject)                AS AverageCost
    (Avg(bs.book_Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY  Book_Subject) - ac.AvgCost) AS 'Difference'
FROM
    BOOK_Subject AS bs
;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        select 
             BOOK.Book_Num,
             BOOK.Book_Title,
             BOOK.Book_SUBJECT,
             book_b.AvgCost,
             (BOOK.Book_Cost - book_b.AvgCost) as Difference 
        FROM BOOK
        LEFT JOIN (
                Select AVG(b.book_Cost) as AvgCost, b.BOOK_Subject
                FROM BOOK b
                group by b.BOOK_Subject
                  ) as book_b on BOOK.BOOK_Subject = book_b.BOOK_Subject
```

Comment: keep the subquery contains only one column and sure the subquery return only one row

Comment: I'm not sure this query will work.  Teh subquery is in the where clause, but isn't used as filter.  Also, I'm not sure why you are averaging only for books that cost 100?